# Login page not working?

Tags: php, sql, authentication

I have some code for a login page i have except it doesn't seem to be working and by this i mean when i enter a correct username and password and click log in, the form just reloads and stays on the same login page. If anyone could suggest some possible solution that would be great, im quite new to PHP and haven't had any luck with fixing this so far. Here is my code :

```
<?php
require_once("nocache.php");
$id = $_POST["id"];
$pword = $_POST["pword"];

if(!empty($_POST)) {
if(!empty($id) || !empty($pword)) {
    require_once("dbconn.php");
    $sql = "select username, school_type from school_info where username = '$id' and password = '$pword'";

    $rs = mysql_query($sql, $dbConn);

    if(mysql_num_rows($rs) > 0) {
        session_start();
        $_SESSION["who"] = $id;
        $_SESSION["school_type"] = mysql_result($rs, 0, "school_type");

        header("location: EOI_home.php");
    }
} else {
    header("location: login.php");
}
}
?>

<form method="POST" action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];?>" id="login">

ID: <input type="text" name="id" /><br/>
pword: <input type="password" name="pword" /><br/>

<input type="submit" value="log in" />&nbsp;
<input type="reset" />

</form>
```

By the way the name of the file i took this code from is login.php

Here are the contents of the dbconn.php file :

```
<?php

$dbConn = mysql_connect("localhost", "twa312", "dam6av9a");

if (!$dbConn){
 die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error()); }
mysql_select_db("test", $dbConn)
 or die ('Database not found ' . mysql_error() );
?>
```

and here is the nochache.php file :

```
<?php
 header("Cache-Control: no-cache");
 header("Expires: -1");
?>
```

Just added the contents of those extra files in case it makes any difference.

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Comment: YOu may also be interested in reading about what to do right after the redirect: http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php :)

Comment: Have you tried putting ob_start(); at the top of your page?

Comment: @PeeHaa埽 I suspect noone writing answers below has followed that header link :)

Comment: Please, put `die('1');` right before `header("location: EOI_home.php");` and tell us if you will see `1`

Comment: Since your script is vulnerable to SQL injection, `pword='OR'1'='1` will suffice to get logged in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no `exit;` after `header("location: EOI_home.php");` redirect. Also the following condition doesn't look right to me..

```
if (!empty($id) || !empty($pword))
```

if `$id` is not empty but `$pword` is it will still login, but won't redirect unless the user has an empty password. It should be..

```
if (!empty($id) && !empty($pword))
```

Comment: ah yes my mistake, didn't even notice that

Answer (score 1):

Move the `session_start` call to the top of the page. If you are outputting anything and prior to hitting that command it's not going to work and if you have warnings turned off then you wouldn't know about it.